# How do you add all the values of a particular column from mysql DB using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Im pulling _balance from a DB and then want to add all the values in the column.. how do I accomplish this with PHP?

SELECT _balance FROM A WHERE X='X' and Y='Y' then add all the values of _balance... ?

Comment: Why not do it from the DB?

Comment: Ît is totally unclear what you mean.

Comment: @Jonnny how do you do it from the db?

Comment: `select sum(column) as somename from table`

Comment: @NaN aggregation http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-sum().php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it from within the DB

```
SELECT SUM(_balance) FROM A WHERE .... // whatever your where clause needs to be
```